# Displays different messages at boot time

Tags: boot, systemd

I see different messages while the system is booting. Some of them have been added recently.

Why are these messages displayed?

```
MDS CPU bug present and SMT on, data leak possible. See https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/hw-vuln/mds.html for more details.
ENERGY_PERF_BIAS: Set to 'normal', was 'performance'
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT, Index (0x00000000E) is beyond end of object (length 0xE) (20230331/exoparg2-393)
ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS15._PLD due to previous error (AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT) (20230331/psparse-529)
pci 0000:02:00.0: [Firmware Bug]: disabling VPD access (can't determine size of non-standard VPD format)
hpet_acpi_add: no address or irqs in _CRS
MXM: GUID detected in BIOS
ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.RP05.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20230331/nsarguments-61)
usbhid 2-2:1.1: couldn't find an input interrupt endpoint
/dev/sda7: clean, 870646/1400832 files, 3881573/5603072 blocks
device-mapper: core: CONFIG_IMA_DISABLE_HTABLE is disabled. Duplicate IMA measurements will not be recorded in the IMA log.
at24 0-0050: supply vcc not found, using dummy regulator
asus_wmi: fan_curve_get_factory_default (0x00110024) failed: -19
asus_wmi: fan_curve_get_factory_default (0x00110025) failed: -19
```

What can I do?